# .htaccess redirect similar URLs (404)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect multiple Urls with a similar structure.

Url 1 : www.example.com/news-1

Url 2 : www.example.com/news-2

Redirect to:

www.example.com/news

I have tried the following code but without success.

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-*$ https://www.example.com/news
```

Its working if I redirect every single on of them to the same page.
But I have 200+ of the news pages, so I´m looking for a solution to solve this problem in 1 single line.

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-1$ https://www.example.com/news
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-2$ https://www.example.com/news
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Solved:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-(.*)$ https://www.example.com/news
```

Comment: but this `/news-(.*)$` give same result for this too `news-sadfasdfsdaf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From My understand,

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/news-(.*)$ https://www.example.com/news
```

the above code also redirect this `https://www.example.com/news-asdfasdfasdf` to `https://www.example.com/news`

if you use like this `#redirectMatch 301 ^/news-([0-9]+)$ https://www.example.com/news` only redirects `https://www.example.com/news-200` to `https://www.example.com/news`

And `https://www.example.com/news-asdfasdfasdf` to 404 page.